# Setting a subview.hidden = false locks up UI for many seconds

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a button to populate a `UIPickerView` on a hidden `UIVisualEffectView`. The user clicks the button, the `VisualEffectView` blurs everything else, and the `PickerView` displays all the names in their contact list (I'm using [SwiftAddressBook](https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook) to do this.)

This works fine except when the user clicks the button, the UI locks up for about 5-10 seconds. I can't find any evidence of heavy CPU or memory usage. If I just print the sorted array to the console, it happens almost immediately. So something about showing the window is causing this bug.

```
@IBAction func getBffContacts(sender: AnyObject) {
    swiftAddressBook?.requestAccessWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
                self.pickerDataSource = [String]()
                for person in people {
                    if (person.firstName != nil && person.lastName != nil) {
                        //println("\(person.firstName!) \(person.lastName!)")
                        self.pickerDataSource.append(person.firstName!)
                    }
                }
            //println(self.pickerDataSource)
            println("done")
            self.sortedNames = self.pickerDataSource.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
            self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
            self.blurView.hidden = false
            }


        }
        else {
            //no success, access denied. Optionally evaluate error
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a threading issue. Read. The. Docs!

`requestAccessWithCompletion` is merely a wrapper for `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`. And what do we find there?

> The completion handler is called on an arbitrary queue

So your code is running in the background. And you must never, never, *never* attempt to interact with the user interface on a background thread. *All* of your code is wrong. You need to step out to the main thread *immediately* at the start of the completion handler. If you don't, disaster awaits.

Comment: Also, this is not directly relevant, but I think letting any wrapper get between you and the ABAddressBook methods is foolish. Things are hard enough as it is without introducing an extra layer of stuff.

Comment: Thanks. I get why you're right but I'm still trying to wrap my brain around threading. What's the proper way to use a completion handler like this in a button and subsequently modify the UI depending on the result of the request?

Comment: Wrap it in a GCD call to `dispatch_async` on the main queue.